# Really confused about Time Complexities

Tags: sorting, time, complexity-theory

I know how to calculate bigO for each algorithm and generally, how it works. For example, finding a specific number in a linked list would be O(N) because you're possibly having to go through every input in the linked list from head to tail. However, what does bigO actually mean in regards to time? How come merge sort can run faster than insertion sort even though insertion sort has a faster "time complexity"? Please give me your input, so I can understand. THankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:

Lets say you have two algorithms `A₁` and `A₂`. The do the same, but the first has a complexity of `Θ(n)` and the second has a complexity in `Θ(n²)`. Both algorithms have different running times. You cannot calculate the running time from the complexity, since it depends on the exact implementation, the computer it is running on, things you cannot see in the complexity and other things. But you can predict the change of running time by the complexity.
Lets say you change the input from length `n` to length `2n`, means you double the input length. Then the running time should also (nearly) double for `A₁`, but it should be about 4 times more for `A₂`, since `(2n)² = 4n²`.

To address the insertion sort vs merge sort example:
The complexity of insertion sort is `O(n²)` and the complexity of merge sort is `O(n log n)`. So merge sort has a better complexity than insertion sort and should also run faster. Maybe (for very short lists) insertion sort runs faster than merge sort, because merge sort has a bigger constant factor hidden in the big-o notation.

Answer (score 0):

the problems/questions you are having are very common at beginners level. I would suggest you to read more about the "asymptotic notations".(there are so many helpful videos and websites on the internet that explains the same) Asymptotic analysis is considering the performance of algorithms when applied to a large database.
Asymptotic notions are basically of three types-

1. Big O
2. Big Omega
3. Theta

Big O is used when we have an **asymptotic upper bound**, that is
Big O of g(n) is equal to f(n) {O(g(n))=f(n)} when there exist positive constant c and n such that
0<=f(n)<=c g(n) for all n>=n0.
(that is, you define a maxima in such a way that your curve f(n) always lies on or below that point.

Big Omega is used when we have an **asymptotic lower bound**

and Theta is used when we have **both an upper bound and a lower bound.**

Now, coming back to your question- insertion sort have a complexity of O(n²) and merge sort O(n log n). at large values (n²) tends to have greater value than (n log n).
lets say n=100.
 in insertion sort the value will be 10,000 and 
 for merge sort it will be (100 log 100) that is 100.2 -> 200.

so, you can see that merge sort will run a lot faster than insertion sort.